# Speeding a Manipulate illustrating convolution

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, manipulate, dynamic, convolution

I'd like to illustrate the mathematical process of convolution ($f(x) \star g(x)$) with an interactive `Manipulate`, but the evaluation is far too slow for a class lecture.

Here's the basic (unoptimized) code:

```
Manipulate[
 GraphicsColumn[{
   Plot[Evaluate@Convolve[f[x], g[x], x, y], {y, 0, 10},
    AxesLabel -> {"z", " (f\[Star]g)(z)"},
    PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, Exclusions -> None,
    Epilog -> {If[(hh = 
          Evaluate@Convolve[f[x], g[x], x, y] /. y -> z) > 0, Green, 
       Red], PointSize[0.04], Point[{z, hh}]}],
   Plot[f[x] g[z - x], {x, 0, 10}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", " f(x) g(z-x)"}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
    Exclusions -> None, Filling -> Axis, 
    FillingStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[0.3], Red], 
      Directive[Opacity[0.3], Green]}],
   Plot[g[z - x], {x, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "g(z-x)"}, 
    PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
    Epilog -> {Black, Line[{{z, 0}, {z, -.2}}], 
      Text[Style["z", Italic, 24, FontFamily -> "Times"], {z, -.33}]},
     Exclusions -> None],
   Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", " f(x)"}, Exclusions -> None]}],
 {f, {Sin, SquareWave, TriangleWave}},
 {g, {UnitBox, HeavisideLambda[#/3] &, UnitTriangle[#/5] &}},
 {{z, 0}, 0, 10},
 ContinuousAction -> False]
```

It is simplest to read the four-part figure from the bottom.  The bottom plot is $f(x)$.  The next-to-bottom is $g(z-x)$, where $z$ is controllable by a slider.  The second plot from the top is the product $f(x) g(z-x)$.  I've used shading to highlight the positive values (green) and negative values (red).  The convolution is the full integral of this function, i.e., the green shaded area minus the red shaded area.

For each chosen value of $z$, the value of that integral is plotted as a point on the top plot, again, colored green if positive, and red if negative.  The curve plotted in the top plot is the convolution, $(f(x) \star g(x))[z]$.

This code is acceptably fast when initialized to $f = \sin x$ and $g = $ UnitBox, as you can confirm by running the code.  I've tried to speed things by using `ContinuousAction -> False`, which helps just a bit.

But the execution is exceedingly slow for more general functions.

I believe that the convolution is re-computed for each setting of $z$, which of course is highly inefficient.

There must be some way in which the convolutions are pre-computed and stored, or numerically evaluated, or otherwise processed to speed the overall evaluation, but I haven't found a way to make the code interactive in real time.

Comment: I have not tried all combinations, but a number of your $f$ and $g$ do not convolve. For example `Convolve[Sin[x],HeavisideLambda[x/3],x,y]` and `Convolve[TriangleWave[x], UnitTriangle[x/5], x, y]`.  Mathematica simply returns them unevaluated. So no point of passing the result to Plot command, as it will hang. It will be better to first test these functions outside of Manipulate to make sure they work OK and fast, then add them to Manipulate. If slowness then result, then we know it is because of Manipulate setting.

Comment: There is an interactive example on the [doc page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Convolve.html). This [page](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Convolution/CI.html) has a few responsive interactive examples as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed by Nasser in comment above, `Convolve` is having difficulty in handling certain combination of `f` and `g`, for example:

```
Convolve[Sin[x], HeavisideLambda[x/3], x, y]
(* Input returned *)
```

Though not documented, when `y` is a numeric value, `Convolve` can compute the convolution **to some degree**:

```
Convolve[Sin[x], HeavisideLambda[x/3], x, 1.2] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.692999, 1.2365} *)

Convolve[Sin[x], HeavisideLambda[x/3], x, 3] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.590948, 4/3 Sin[3/2]^2 Sin[3]} *)
```

But this is just too slow. What's more, this hidden functionality is unstable:

```
Convolve[Sin[x], HeavisideLambda[x/3], x, 3.]
(* Input returned *)
```

So we need a better numeric solver. It's straightforward to define numeric convolution via `NIntegrate`:

```
Clear[NConvolve]; 
NConvolve[f_, g_, x_, y_?NumericQ] := 
 NConvolve[f, g, x, y] = 
  NIntegrate[f (g /. x -> y - x), {x, -∞, ∞}, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
```

The `AccuracyGoal -> 5` is added to avoid the difficulty caused by zero integration. To speed things up, we pre-compute those convolutions:

```
{L, R} = {0, 10}; step = 1/10;

rule = HeavisideLambda -> UnitTriangle;

Do[
  NConvolve[f[x], g[x] /. rule, x, 
   y], {f, {Sin, SquareWave, TriangleWave}}, {g, {UnitBox, HeavisideLambda[#/3] &, 
    UnitTriangle[#/5] &}}, {y, L, R, step}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {53.0485, Null} *)
```

The `rule` is added because `HeavisideLambda` is not suitable for numeric calculation.

> **Remark**
>
> The convolution only needs to be calculated once. We can then store
> the result using e.g.
>
> ```
> DumpSave["convolve.mx", NConvolve]
> ```
>
> and load the result using e.g.
>
> ```
> <<convolve.mx
> ```

The next optimization is to use `Grid` instead of `GraphicsColumn`, which is slow:

```
Clear[convplot, fgplot, gplot, fplot]
convplot[f_, g_] :=(*convplot[f,g]=*)
 ListLinePlot[Table[{y, NConvolve[f[x], g[x] /. rule, x, y]}, {y, L, R, step}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", " (f⋆g)(z)"}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}]
point[f_, g_, z_] := 
 Graphics@{If[(hh = NConvolve[f[x], g[x] /. rule, x, z]) > 0, Green, Red], 
   PointSize[0.04], Point[{z, hh}]}
fgplot[f_, g_, z_] :=(*fgplot[f,g,z]=*)
 Plot[f[x]  g[z - x], {x, L, R}, AxesLabel -> {"x", " f(x) g(z-x)"}, 
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, Exclusions -> None, Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[0.3], Red], Directive[Opacity[0.3], Green]}]
gplot[g_, z_] :=(*gplot[g,z]=*)
 Plot[g[z - x], {x, L, R}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "g(z-x)"}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
  Epilog -> {Black, Line[{{z, 0}, {z, -.2}}], 
    Text[Style["z", Italic, 24, FontFamily -> "Times"], {z, -.33}]}, 
  Exclusions -> None]
fplot[f_] :=(*fplot[f]=*)
 Plot[f[x], {x, L, R}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", " f(x)"}, 
  Exclusions -> None]

Manipulate[
 Grid[{{Show[convplot[f, g], point[f, g, z]], fgplot[f, g, z]}, {gplot[g, z], 
    fplot[f]}}], {f, {Sin, SquareWave, TriangleWave}}, {g, {UnitBox, 
   HeavisideLambda[#/3] &, UnitTriangle[#/5] &}}, {z, L, R, step}]
```

Notice I've set an explicit `step` in `Manipulate` so the pre-computed values will be called. We can add memorization for `convplot`, etc to speed up the code further, but it's not quite necessary in my view, because the current implementation is already smooth even on my old laptop:

[image]

Comment: Oh how very nice.  Thanks for all your efforts.  A hearty $+1$ and $\checkmark$.  I'd been working on *pre* computing convolutions and then merely reading off/implementing the function.  (My students will love this.)